# SSIS Excel Import (Column Names Changing)

Tags: ssis

I have an Excel file that loosely resembles the following format:

[image]

I'll explain the next step of the SSIS element first as the column names are not "important" as I am un-pivoting the data in a data flow to start getting it usable:

[image]

The issue is, the file will be updated - years and quarters will be removed (historical), new ones added to replace the old ones.  That means, as we all know, the metadata on a data flow is broken.

The cell range and position etc. will always remain the same.

Is there a way it can be handled in a data flow with the column names (2016q1) being fluid?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to like this as it also does the pivot:

Using C# Script component source:

Add namespace:
Using System.Data.OleDb;

Add your 4 output columns and select data types:

Add code to new row section.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        /*
          Add rows by calling the AddRow method on the member variable named "<Output Name>Buffer".
          For example, call MyOutputBuffer.AddRow() if your output was named "MyOutput".
        */
        string fileName = @"C:\test.xlsx";
        string SheetName = "Sheet1";
        string cstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        OleDbConnection xlConn = new OleDbConnection(cstr);
        xlConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand xlCmd = xlConn.CreateCommand();
        xlCmd.CommandText = "Select * from [" + SheetName + "$]";
        xlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataReader rdr = xlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        //int rowCt = 0; //Counter

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++) //loop from 3 column to last
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.ColA = rdr[0].ToString();
                Output0Buffer.ColB = rdr[1].ToString();
                Output0Buffer.FactName = rdr.GetName(i);
                Output0Buffer.FactValue = rdr.GetDouble(i);
            }


            //rowCt++; //increment counter
        }
        xlConn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You're a legend Keith!  Only tweak I did was

Output0Buffer.ScenarioValue = rdr.IsDBNull(i) == true ? 0 : rdr.GetDouble(i);

To counter any DBNulls coming through

Comment: I know you are done with this, but if you do not want to create records for nulls then wrap the Output Buffers with an if statement if (!rdr.IsDBNull(i))

Comment: @KeithL Thanks for providing this great example. I'm trying to do something very similar  but struggling to get over the start line. I've posted on  Stack Overflow and would realy apprecaite a few pointers if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61514481/how-to-get-an-ssis-c-sharp-script-task-to-read-from-excel-via-oledb

Answer (score 1):

If the columns remain in order, then you can skip header rows and select 1st row does not contain headers.

Comment: But that's the thing Keith and as mentioned, columns will eventually drop off e.g. 2016Q1, 2016Q2, 2016Q3 and 2016Q4 will drop off on the next file, everything will shift left and a new year with quarters will get tagged on to the right.