# SQL Server : import Excel and place column name and the value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, database, ssis

I have an Excel file that needs to be imported into SQL Server.

Excel sheet:

| Product | 202147 | 202148 | 202149 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prod-A | 15 | 10 | 11 |
| Prod-B | 7 | 18 | 16 |

This needs to be read into a SQL Server table `MyData`:

| YearWeek | Product | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202147 | Prod-A | 15 |
| 202147 | Prod-B | 7 |
| 202148 | Prod-A | 10 |
| 202148 | Prod-B | 18 |
| 202149 | Prod-A | 11 |
| 202149 | Prod-B | 16 |

How can I do this in an SSIS import?

Comment: Have you tried reading it into a staging table and then using [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15#unpivot-example) on it yet?

Comment: This will help you if you don't know the column names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693919/ssis-excel-import-column-names-changing/47700332#47700332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that directly on SSIS import. On the other hand, you can import your excel on a table and then run the following sql query to achieve your goal:

```
select yearWeek, product, value
from myData
unpivot (value for yearWeek in ([202147], [202148], [202149])) up
order by 1,2

-- Result
/*
yearWeek    product value
202147      Prod-A  15
202147      Prod-B  7
202148      Prod-A  10
202148      Prod-B  18
202149      Prod-A  11
202149      Prod-B  16
*/
```

Comment: It gets much more difficult when you don't hard code it